# How to update an Input file (image) in vueJS and Django rest?

Tags: javascript, django, vue.js, django-rest-framework, axios

Good morning, I'm currently working to the edit page for a blog using VueJS and Django Rest Framework. When I try to upload a photo I receive an error *"the sended datas are not a file"* and I' not currently able to select the current image (the default image is Null). The questions are how to make a working changing photo form and how to start with the image already charged in the JSon file. Thanks for all answers. Right now I have not made the admin system.

**VueJS**

```
<template>
    <h1>ARTICOLO</h1>
    <form @submit="onSubmit">
        <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Titolo" v-model="form.title">
        <input type="text" name="desc" placeholder="Descrizione" v-model="form.desc">
        <input type="text" name="category" v-model="form.category">
        <input type="file" name="image" @change="EditImage" >
        <input type="text" name="author" v-model="form.author">
        <input type="text" name="author" v-model="form.slug">
        <textarea name="text" v-model="form.text"></textarea>

        <button type="submit" @click= "editPost">Edit</button>
    </form>
</template>
<script>
import axios from 'axios';
import { getAPI } from '../api'
export default {
    data () {
        return{
            Postslug: this.$route.params.Postslug,
            form: {
                title:"",
                desc:"",
                text:"",
                category:"",
                date:"",
                author:"",
                image:"",
                slug:"",
            },
            selectedFile: null
        }
    },
    methods: {
        // Form method
        onSubmit(event){
            event.preventDefault();     
            axios.put(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/api/edit/${this.Postslug}`, this.form).then(response => {
              this.form.title = response.data.title
              this.form.desc = response.data.desc
              this.form.text = response.data.text
              this.form.image = response.data.image
              this.form.category = response.data.category
              this.form.author = response.data.author
              this.form.slug = response.data.slug
              alert('Ok')
            })
            .catch(err => {
              console.log(err)
            })
        },
        EditImage(event){
            this.selectedFile = event.target.files[0]
            console.log(event);
        },
        editPost(){
            const fd = FormData();
            fd.append('image', this.selectedFile, this.selectedFile.name)
            axios.put(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/api/edit/${this.Postslug}`, fd)
            .then(response =>{
                console.log(response);
            })
        }
        
    },
    created() {
        getAPI.get(`blog/api/edit/${this.Postslug}`)
            .then(response => {
              this.form.title = response.data.title
              this.form.desc = response.data.desc
              this.form.text = response.data.text
              this.form.date = response.data.date
              this.form.image = response.data.image
              this.form.category = response.data.category
              this.form.author = response.data.author
              this.form.slug = response.data.slug
            })
            .catch(err => {
              console.log(err)
            })
        },
    name: 'AdminEditArticle',
}
</script>
<style lang="sass" scoped>
</style>
```

**Axios get**

```
import axios from 'axios'
const getAPI = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000',
    timeout: 1000,
})
export { getAPI }
```

**Serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework.fields import ReadOnlyField
from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer, SerializerMethodField
from Blog.models import *

class PostListSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    author = SerializerMethodField()
    category = SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'author', 'category', 'image', 'desc', 'text', 'slug', 'date')

    def get_author(self, obj):
        return str(obj.author.username)
    
    def get_category(self, obj):
        return str(obj.category.name)


class PostDetailSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'author', 'category', 'image', 'desc', 'text', 'slug', 'date')
        def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
            if self.instance.image:
                self.instance.image.delete()
            return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**Models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model): 
    title = models.CharField(max_length=299)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,default=ANONYMOUS_USER_ID, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category,default=ANONYMOUS_USER_ID, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True)
    desc = models.TextField()
    text = RichTextField(blank = True, null = True )
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(null = True, blank = True, unique=True)

    class Meta: # Order post by date
        ordering = ['-date',]

    def __str__(self): # Display title 
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self): # #TODO da cambiare
        return reverse("listpost")

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs): # Auto Slug Field
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

Check [drf settings](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/#fileuploadparser) to add `rest_framework.parsers.FileUploadParser`. Parses raw file upload content. The request.data property will be a dictionary with a single key 'file' containing the uploaded file.

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": (
        "rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication",
        "rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication",
    ),
    "DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES": ("rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated",),
    "DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS": [
        "django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend",
        "rest_framework.filters.OrderingFilter",
    ],
    "DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS": "rest_framework.pagination.LimitOffsetPagination",
    "DEFAULT_METADATA_CLASS": "rest_framework.metadata.SimpleMetadata",
    "DEFAULT_SCHEMA_CLASS": "rest_framework.schemas.openapi.AutoSchema",
    "PAGE_SIZE": 50,
    "MAX_LIMIT": 50,
    "TEST_REQUEST_DEFAULT_FORMAT": "json",
    "DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES": (
        "rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer",
        "rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer",
    ),
    "DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES": (
        "rest_framework.parsers.JSONParser",
        "rest_framework.parsers.FormParser",
        "rest_framework.parsers.MultiPartParser",
        "rest_framework.parsers.FileUploadParser",
    ),
}
```

Comment: Provide url and view, pls

Comment: Check in the browser developer console weather `this.form` has an image before sending `put` request

Comment: It has not an input image by defalut

Comment: You add file to `selectedFile: null` but your `put` sends `form`. You should put file to the appropriate form field to send it.  Edited comment

Comment: I tried but the file is not readed, I'll retry and send the code if it 'll not work

Comment: I've tried selectedFile: form.image but it gave me like 10 errors in the console

Comment: `editPost` duplicates `onSubmit`. They should be merged and you should keep only one

Comment: Ok, is not giveing an error but is not working the put method, also with the other fields (I've tried text field for example) and the default image is still not working idk why